# How to add comments to range of cells using EPPlus

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

I'm generating an Excel file for the user to do stuff with. I'm populating values, and some of them will have comments. Adding the values to a range of cells works perfectly. Adding comments to more than one cell at a time gives me an error when I try opening the Excel file. Visual Studio acts like everything'll be fine, but when I open the file it says:

"We found a problem with some content in [filename]. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes."
I click yes, I get a message that says "Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content.
Removed Records: Comments from /xl/comments1.xml part (Comments)"

Here's the log file listing repairs:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>-<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
<logFileName>error272000_02.xml</logFileName>
<summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\Users\aletreb\Downloads\Import_20190826_7E'sSales (11).xlsx'</summary>
-<removedRecords>
<removedRecord>Removed Records: Comments from /xl/comments1.xml part (Comments)</removedRecord>
</removedRecords>
</recoveryLog>`

So when the file opens, only the very first cell in the range still has the comment.

```
    var worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
    var customerName = bulkUpload.CustomerId != 0 ? _customerModel.GetCustomerByID(bulkUpload.CustomerId).CustomerName : "No Customer";
    var finalRow = bulkUpload.UnitCount != null && bulkUpload.UnitCount > 0 ? (int)bulkUpload.UnitCount + 1 : 2;

    var headerRow = new List<string> {
        "CustomerID", // A1
        "VIN", // B1
        "Unit Number", // C1
        "Year", // D1
        "Make", // E1
        "Model", // F1
        "Contact Name", // G1
        "Phone Number", // H1
        "Fax Number" // I1
    };

    var customerIdrange = worksheet.SelectedRange[2, 1, finalRow, 1];
    customerIdrange.Value = bulkUpload.CustomerId;
    customerIdrange.AddComment(customerName, "author"); // Problem here
```

`

I've tried using the AddComments() method on Excel Ranges of cells, selected using Cells["A2:A5"], SelectedRange["A2:A5"], Cells[2,1,5,1], and SelectedRange[2,1,5,1]. Everything seems fine in Visual Studio, but I keep getting the same error when I open the Excel file.

I know I can use AddComment() to add comments to individual cells, but I really don't want to have to loop through each cell and do them one at a time. The documentation is making it sound like I should be able to add it to a range as well, so I'd much rather do that.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoiding using the `[int FromRow, int FromCol, int ToRow, int ToCol]` indexer since the `AddComment` logic does not seem to properly support.  But a `for`will works properly:

```
//var customerIdrange = worksheet.SelectedRange[2, 1, finalRow, 1];
for (var i = 2; i <= finalRow; i++)
{
    var customerIdrange = worksheet.SelectedRange[i, 1];
    customerIdrange.Value = bulkUpload.CustomerId;
    customerIdrange.AddComment(customerName, "author"); // Problem here 
}
```